# How make better timeout function

Tags: go, timeout, raft

I was using `time.After(time)`, which is working OK.

My question is: Is it precise and should I use this or should I make my own function? I am using this with a Raft Consensus algorithm implementation.

Comment: depends on what you mean by accurate. There is overhead to creating the timer, channel, and calling the function, so calling nanosecond-level intervals isn't too useful.

Comment: It is more precise than you would reasonably be able to create yourself, as time.After() has a bit of magic and ties down to the runtime eventloop, using non-public APIs.

Comment: if you need to shave off a little overhead (200ns an 2 allocs on my system), you can create the a timer ahead of time, and reuse it instead of calling time.After

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you mean [time.After](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#After)?

I wrote a quick benchmark to answer this question.

Run with `go test -run XXX -bench . time_after_test.go`

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func BenchmarkTimeAfterSecond(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        <-time.After(time.Second)
    }
}

func BenchmarkTimeAfterMillisecond(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        <-time.After(time.Millisecond)
    }
}

func BenchmarkTimeAfterMicrosecond(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        <-time.After(time.Microsecond)
    }
}

func BenchmarkTimeAfterNanosecond(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        <-time.After(time.Nanosecond)
    }
}
```

This gave this under go1.2 on a linux amd64 machine

```
BenchmarkTimeAfterSecond                   1    1000132210 ns/op
BenchmarkTimeAfterMillisecond           2000       1106763 ns/op
BenchmarkTimeAfterMicrosecond          50000         62649 ns/op
BenchmarkTimeAfterNanosecond         5000000           493 ns/op
```

So the answer is accurate to 0.1-0.2 mS or so on my machine.

This is extremely OS and hardware dependent though so will vary on your OS and hardware of choice.

Comment: you don't need a select around a single channel read, you're just adding to the overhead.

Comment: @JimB good point... however it makes only about 6 ns difference on my machine when I tested it just now.

Comment: People come to SO for examples of ways to do things.  Wrapping a single channel receive in a select block may not have a tremendous performance impact, but it's a lot of unnecessary complexity you're putting in front of already confused users.

Comment: @Dustin I'm almost certain that the OP is using `select` for making timeouts as it is the way it is done in Go, just with more `case` statements.  That is why I wrote it like that anyway.

Comment: Then your benchmark would be more accurate for that case if it also included a receive from a channel that wasn't ready to send.  I'd also include a case for nil, as well as a case where the timeout doesn't fire, which would be catastrophic in these short timeout cases.

Comment: well, this is all moot anyway, since OP hasn't provided any code, and we don't know what he means by "precise".

Comment: what about the cooperative scheduling of the go-routine so if one is busy  in doing computation then it will not handover the execution to other go-routine and then it will starve other go routine (it might possible there is one go-routine that is received timeout that can be delayed.. it happened with my program)

Comment: @YogenderSolanki, Go isn't realtime, so you have to accept the limitations of the runtime. That said, if you have a busy loop where you're not calling any functions, and you're starving other goroutines, and you can add a runtime.GoSched. This has nothing to do with timers, and you're still not going to be able to create a timer any better than the builtin time.Timer.

Comment: thanks.. i was hoping that there is another option exist @JimB